# Converting an Extended class to support parallel execution in multi threading mode with minimum lines of change

Tags: java, multithreading

This is the code which I written early when I executed sequentially .I get a Webdriver driver instance from an  external class called WebDriverFactory which has a
ThreadLocal driver. So now I am running  on parallel mode and  "Chrome" browser is given in   TestcaseOne while TestcaseTwo has Firefox as browser, and based on the Browser, driver instance is initiated.

In order to  have less statements in TestcaseOne and TestcaseTwo, I extended the Command, so without creating an object I can call the methods like Click and pass the parameters.

```
    public class TestcaseOne extends Command{
    //Getting a driver instance from a class which has ThreadLocal driver.
    WebDriverFactory.setDriver("Chrome");
    driver= WebDriverFactory.getDriver();

         click(element,driver)

    }

public class Command{
      public static String  driver;

public void click(WebElement element, String driver) {
driver.click();
}
```

I have like 100 of classes with 100k statements of this.(Find and replacement from an IDE, also only work up to some extend) I know how to solve this by changing the each statment but  it takes time. However, by keeping the TestcaseOne,TestcaseTwo as it is, is there any way you see to fix it by changing only Command class?

Here is my WebDriverFactory class.

```
public class WebDriverFactory {
    //Define a ThreadLocal Static variable for the Webdriver.
    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

    public static void setDriver(String browser ) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {

            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--incognito");
            driver.set(new ChromeDriver(options));

        }
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver.get();
    }
```

Comment: Why would `driver` be static? In your example, this would mean all vehicles are driven by the same person.

Comment: Why are you using a static variable and method in the first place?  That gives you, at any given time, the same driver driving all cars in existence.

Comment: Ok , let me run it without it , it  was a code I wrote for a  one thread.

Comment: But to the actual question, yes, you can access a public static variable of any type via its fully-qualified name from anywhere.  But why are you asking us? Your compiler and test would have told you if that were not so.  If you're observing unexpected behavior then please ask about the actual issue you're facing, and include a [mre].

Comment: Honestly, the real answer is: step back, and get a good book and read what `static` is, and how, for example, it doesn't take part in polymorphism at all in Java.

Comment: I modified the code with  the reason. Hope it's clear. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, @SameeraDeSilva, this is still not clear. If your question is really about the `Testcase` and `Command` classes you added at the end, then please rewrite the question to be about them and remove the `Vehicle` and `Car` examples.

Comment: I am sorry , I changed the question.Hope it's clear now.